# Qt Socket problems

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, linker

I can't figure out why I'm getting these errors. I'm using Qt 4.7.4. I'm trying to make a client/server program which uses sockets to communicate. I have working code (works in visual studio 2008) with the winsock2 library. This code refuses to work with Qt, I tried for a a couple of days. I keep getting linker errors, so I decided to try to start from scratch with QTcpSocket. I included all the required include paths in the .pro file, and I am getting linker errors.

This is my client class:

**toplevelcomms.h**

```
#ifndef TOPLEVELCOMMS_H
#define TOPLEVELCOMMS_H

#include <QObject>
#include "inireader.h"
#include "WinSock2.h"
#include <QDialog>
#include <qtcpsocket.h>
#include <qhostaddress.h>


/** This class sends/receives information through sockets.
 *
 */

class TopLevelComms : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TopLevelComms(QString hostIP, quint16 hostPort);
    void connect();

private:
    QTcpSocket *tcpSocket;
    QHostAddress hostAddress;
    quint16 hostPort;


};

#endif // TOPLEVELCOMMS_H
```

**toplevelcomms.cpp**

```
#include "toplevelcomms.h"
#include "stdio.h"

TopLevelComms::TopLevelComms(QString hostIP, quint16 hostPort)
{
    tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    hostAddress.setAddress(hostIP);
    this->hostPort = hostPort;

}


void TopLevelComms::connect(){
    //tcpSocket->connectToHost();
}
```

**This is the .pro file**

```
include( $${PWD}/../qwtbuild.pri )
include( $${PWD}/../qwtconfig.pri )

QT       += core gui

TARGET = TSLSuite
TEMPLATE = app

... // *all my files are declared here*


CONFIG += qwt

INCLUDEPATH += $${PWD}/../include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/msvc2008/include/Qt
INCLUDEPATH += C:/QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/msvc2008/bin
INCLUDEPATH += C:/QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/msvc2008/include/QtNetwork

LIBS += -LC:/Qwt-6.0.1/lib -lqwt
LIBS += -LC:/Qt/4.7.4/lib -lQtSvg
```

**This is the output :**

```
11:33:57: Running build steps for project TSLSuite...
11:33:57: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:33:57: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile.Release all
linking release\TSLSuite.exe 
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QHostAddress::~QHostAddress(void)" (__imp_??1QHostAddress@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0TopLevelComms@@QAE@VQString@@G@Z$0
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall QHostAddress::setAddress(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setAddress@QHostAddress@@QAE_NABVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall TopLevelComms::TopLevelComms(class QString,unsigned short)" (??0TopLevelComms@@QAE@VQString@@G@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QTcpSocket::QTcpSocket(class QObject *)" (__imp_??0QTcpSocket@@QAE@PAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall TopLevelComms::TopLevelComms(class QString,unsigned short)" (??0TopLevelComms@@QAE@VQString@@G@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QHostAddress::QHostAddress(void)" (__imp_??0QHostAddress@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall TopLevelComms::TopLevelComms(class QString,unsigned short)" (??0TopLevelComms@@QAE@VQString@@G@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QTcpSocket::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QTcpSocket@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QTcpSocket::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QTcpSocket@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QTcpSocket::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QTcpSocket@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::isSequential(void)const " (?isSequential@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_NXZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractSocket::close(void)" (?close@QAbstractSocket@@UAEXXZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::atEnd(void)const " (?atEnd@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_NXZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __int64 __thiscall QAbstractSocket::bytesAvailable(void)const " (?bytesAvailable@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_JXZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __int64 __thiscall QAbstractSocket::bytesToWrite(void)const " (?bytesToWrite@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_JXZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::canReadLine(void)const " (?canReadLine@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_NXZ)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::waitForReadyRead(int)" (?waitForReadyRead@QAbstractSocket@@UAE_NH@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::waitForBytesWritten(int)" (?waitForBytesWritten@QAbstractSocket@@UAE_NH@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall QAbstractSocket::readData(char *,__int64)" (?readData@QAbstractSocket@@MAE_JPAD_J@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall QAbstractSocket::readLineData(char *,__int64)" (?readLineData@QAbstractSocket@@MAE_JPAD_J@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall QAbstractSocket::writeData(char const *,__int64)" (?writeData@QAbstractSocket@@MAE_JPBD_J@Z)
toplevelcomms.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QTcpSocket::~QTcpSocket(void)" (__imp_??1QTcpSocket@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall QTcpSocket::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQTcpSocket@@UAEPAXI@Z)
release\TSLSuite.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals

jom 1.0.6 - empower your cores

command failed with exit code 1120
command failed with exit code 2
11:33:58: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project TSLSuite (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I've been getting many frustrating problems with Qt...I can never seem to find out how to properly add libraries, and every new thing I try takes forever to get working...am I missing something??

Please answer the following questions:

1. What is wrong with my current code, and how do I fix it?
2. What am I doing wrong with Qt? Why is it so hard for me to use new libraries and classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `.pro` file you need to add the network module:

```
QT       += core gui network
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I really enjoy Qt, however I'm missing some basic knowledge of how to properly use different libraries and incorporate them into my project. Is there some material you can point me to so I can better educate myself?

Comment: @PTBG: When using Qt i found the [Qt documentation quite helpful](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/) and sufficient. It looks like a lot at first, but after stepping through the basics you'll have a better overview of where to dive in deeper.

Comment: I'll start reading through. I really appreciate your help, many thanks again!